# 2N3904, Power Supply & FuncGen results on strange output on the scope

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn, common-collector

I was having trouble with a Collpitts oscillator output, it was distorted, so wanted to check if I am indeed in the linear region of the transistor, so I decided to use the func gen to check that.

However I am getting some strange reading on the scope that I cannot understand.

Attached is the schematic and what I see on the scope.

V1 is the power supply, V2 is the func gen. Func Gen config is 1kHz Frequence, 1V Amplitute, 2V Offset. The BJT is a 2N3904.

Pink is a probe at base, Yellow at emitter.

Any one can understand what am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Zooming in, I see:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85319/why-emitter-follower-is-so-noisy-and-distorted-in-large-signal/85328#85328

Comment: Yes, thanks @BrianDrummond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transistor is oscillating. As Elliot suggests adding a resistor in series with the base will cure it but it is not because of the resistor limiting the base current.

Emitter followers with a capacitative load often will have a negative input resistance that can cause oscillation. Adding a small resistor (usually only a few ohms) can avoid this by reducing the 'Q' of the circuit..

If you analyze the circuit including all the parasitic capacitances and inductances it will actually be very similar to a Colpitts oscillator.

The load of the scope probe will be part of the output capacitance, the wiring will create the inductances and the transistor internal capacitance plays an important part.

[image: Emitter follower including parasitics]

From [EDN - Emitter Followers as oscillators](https://www.edn.com/emitter-followers-as-colpitts-oscillators/)

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why the base resistor was needed since we have the relatively big collector resistor that limits the BC current anyway. Mystery solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Add a resistor between the function generator and the transistor base to limit the base current. Something like 1kΩ should work.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Any idea why this is happening?