# Debugging Signal Distortion/Oscillation

Tags: amplifier, audio, oscillation, distortion

Finally built up the circuit below that I've been designing/toying with in LTSpice and its working OK but I'm wondering if an experienced eye might be able to quickly label what/why the oddities are in the signals I see on my oscilloscope.

I'm probably missing a crucial component/layout choice and I'm hoping its a typical beginner mistake I'm making!

**Circuit**
[image]

**Input: 300Hz sine wave:**
[image]

- *I notice that with the 300Hz input, when I increase the input level
  the 'width' of the distorted parts widens - if that is a useful
  observation for me to diagnose my issue?*

**Input: ActualMusic:**
[image]

**Actual Build**
[image]

- Let me know if I can/need to explain any of the spaghetti!

Comment: For audio? Your method of creating a +Vcc, -Vcc is not wonderful, and its wasteful of power. The impedance of this power source at 20 Hz is a bit high. Where are those two 1000uF located? They should go directly from pwr transistor collectors to the 4-ohm ground point.

Comment: Looks like a grounding layout problem to me. Show your layout.

Comment: This is similar to the self-excitation (oscillation) of the amplifier. Try adding a 5..30 pF capacitor in parallel to R16.

Comment: @Andyaka - Added an image, let me know if I can clarify any of the mess that it is :S

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks, My slightly singed finger found out how wasteful it is over R15/17 :What would you advise I research/build instead (i sadly lack a dual output bench power supply)

Comment: You need to connect 10R in series with 100nF in parallel to the speaker to eliminate its induction.

Comment: Why didn't you use a Miller compensation capacitor across Q9?

Comment: It’s a layout problem. Well, let’s put it this way, it’s a pretty awful way to test an audio amplifier circuit (on breadboard). There may be other things but this is the main issue.

Comment: Good call also from @G36

Comment: You need to also wholly segregate any input signal from passing any current in its 0 volt connection to the amplifier that is anything else other than signal current. There’s no evidence of that in the picture.

Comment: Possibly relevant... your output transistors are emitter followers... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85319/why-emitter-follower-is-so-noisy-and-distorted-in-large-signal/85328#85328

Comment: Ask yourself if your amplifier must be DC-coupled. If not, make "-Vcc" into ground, and "+Vcc" becomes +20V. Then AC-couple the transistor emitters to the 4-ohm load with 2000uF. You'll also have to add a signal-input coupling capacitor, and add a capacitor in series with R10 to ground.

Answer (score 0):

Get 4 of the 6v lantern batteries. Wire as +_12v.

Retest.

Regarding stability, your only gain_stage is Q9. Install 100pF or 1,000pF
from base to collector.