# Purpose of additional base resistors in p-p a/b audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio

I'm looking into the changes made from one generation of an amplifier circuit to the next generation. They have been using the same topology and same components, but the changes which I can spot are lower input impedance (33k-12k,) removal of a couple of resistors and reduced value of the corresponding capacitators in the input area along with the lower value of the feedback resistor increasing the feedback.

They have also added low value base resistors. What is the purpose of adding these resistors?

[image]

Comment: The 22 ohm resistors will help current sharing.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85319/why-emitter-follower-is-so-noisy-and-distorted-in-large-signal/85328#85328

Comment: One possible use of the base resistors - some amps (Fender, for example) use fusible resistors there as fuses as much as resistors, so that a blown output transistor won't take the driver transistors and other components with it.

They also help with current sharing, and it's hard to say how much of which function is more important.

Answer (score 4):

An output Zobel network was added (series R-C in lower right corner). This is used to present a stable and friendly (resistive) load impedance to the amplifier at high frequency to make it more stable. Or rather, it makes it easier to design the amplifier since the HF load impedance is known instead of an unknown determined by to cable and loudspeaker inductance.

However they also added another Zobel network right at the output of the amp, before the relay (to the left of the relay on the schematic, 10 ohms in series with 0.1µF, part numbers unreadable).

This makes no sense:

- One 5R+200nF network costs less than two 10R+100nF so why two?
- The proper place to add this network is before the relay, so it presents a nice resistive load to the output of the amp even when the relay is open. Without load the output stage can oscillate. So one Zobel network is in the right place, the other is on the wrong side of the relay.

I notice the conspicuous absence of an output L//R network, which is usually put in series with the output to protect the amplifier from nasty loads like capacitive loudspeakers or cables.

And then, the unusually high value base resistors on output transistors. This is something you'd want to avoid, because the hFe on these output transistors isn't that high so base current can be substantial, and voltage drop on the base resistor will limit output voltage swing. It also increases distortion through various mechanisms: at high power it lets the transistor's nonlinear hFe create a nonlinear current-dependent voltage drop across the base resistor, and at low power it adds crossover distortion by acting like a higher value emitter resistor. However, high value base resistors will also prevent oscillation in the output stage, although ferrite beads will do the same with none of the above drawbacks.

So I guess the absence of an output L//R network made the amp unstable on some loads. So instead of fixing the problem by adding a L//R network, they applied a variety of band-aids, like two Zobel networks and extra base resistor.

Comment: Thank you for the insight!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, and intended to experiment a bit, where would the ferrite bead be applied and at what approximate value? I would like to make this amplifier stable and safe without the base resistors. I’ll be experimenting in spice so I don’t burn the house down. But spice doesn’t really always reflect real world imperfections that’s why I prefer to trust people with better knowledge. Also, would it be necessary to add a L//R network at the output aswell as the ferrite bead solution?

Comment: I've had success with these [ferrite beads](https://secure.reichelt.com/fr/fr/perle-d-att-nuation-3-5-x-3-mm-dfp-3-0-p7110.html) to prevent oscillations. Usually they're placed on the transistor base pin. But you can also replace the resistors with a bit of wire with the ferrite bead threaded on it. Careful they're a bit conductive, so the bead will short base to collector if it touches the middle pin, so it's a good idea to wrap it in some kapton tape.

Comment: The L//R network is necessary if the load is capacitive (check your loudspeaker crossover), or a high capacitance cable. Otherwise it's not absolutely necessary, but it costs so little...

Comment: Ferrite beads and base resistors prevent local HF oscillation of the output transistors. L//R prevents oscillation of the whole loop at a lower frequency due to a capacitive load.

Comment: Thank you very much! My loudspeakers are not very capacitive and the cables are short, but I would prefer to be on the safe side, how small could a L//R filter be and still be somewhat effective? Thinking 0,5uh and 8R?

Comment: It's usually around these values, 0.5-1µH and 5-8 ohm so you're pretty safe.

Answer (score 0):

The 22 ohm base resistors for the output transistors could help fault finding. Also, they could be sized to blow open when the output stage fails so the driver  stage can be saved. This reduces repair labour time.

Comment: The fault finding does not justify so many additional elements in a mass produced circuit. The transistors which does not face the outside world do not need protection, but the output of the circuit.